# Submit command line arguments to a pyspark job on airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a pyspark job available on GCP Dataproc to be triggered on airflow as shown below:

```
config = help.loadJSON("batch/config_file")

MY_PYSPARK_JOB = {
    "reference": {"project_id": "my_project_id"},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": "my_cluster_name"},
    "pyspark_job": {
        "main_python_file_uri": "gs://file/loc/my_spark_file.py"]
        "properties": config["spark_properties"]
        "args": <TO_BE_ADDED>
    },
}
```

I need to supply command line arguments to this pyspark job as show below [this is how I am running my pyspark job from command line]:

```
spark-submit gs://file/loc/my_spark_file.py --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2
```

I am providing the arguments to my pyspark job using **"configparser"**. Therefore, arg1 is the key and val1 is the value from my spark-submit commant above.

How do I define the **"args"** param in the **"MY_PYSPARK_JOB"** defined above [equivalent to my command line arguments]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this conundrum.
If we are making use of ConfigParser, the key has to be specified as below [irrespective of whether the argument is being passed as command or on airflow]:

```
--arg1
```

In airflow, the configs are passed as a Sequence[str] (as mentioned by @Betjens below) and each argument is defined as follows:

```
arg1=val1
```

Therefore, as per my requirement, command line arguments are defined as depicted below:

```
"args": ["--arg1=val1",
    "--arg2=val2"]
```

*PS:* Thank you @Betjens for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `Sequence[str]`. If you check [DataprocSubmitJobOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2af13f28126a24465624fcc568c88cf6c6e6824d/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L1761)  you will see that the params `job` implements a class [google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.Job](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataproc/latest/google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.Job).

```
class DataprocSubmitJobOperator(BaseOperator):
...
    :param job: Required. The job resource. If a dict is provided, it must be of the same form as the protobuf message.
    :class:`~google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.Job`
```

So, on the section about job type `pySpark` which is  [google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.PySparkJob](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataproc/latest/google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.PySparkJob):

> args  Sequence[str]
> Optional. The arguments to pass to the driver. Do not include arguments, such as `--conf`, that can be set as job properties, since a collision may occur that causes an incorrect job submission.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am assuming below is an example of Sequence[str]?    
        "args": [
        "arg1=val1",
        "arg2=val2"
         ]

Comment: well it does not implies the way you are passing but based on the `cli` I think you can try using `"args":["--arg1 val1","--arg2 val2" ]` .

Comment: I do get your point. Let me give this a try and see how it works.

Comment: Please also try this:  `"args": ["arg1":"val1","arg2":"val2"]`

Comment: Yes, the plan is to try all 3 possibilities. "--arg1 val1", "arg1=val1" and "arg1":"val1".

Comment: I managed to solve this. Kindly find my answer below. Thank you for all your suggestions.